# Send a mail with Zend Framework : "Connection could not be established"

Tags: php, zend-framework, smtp, sendmail

I'm working on an "old" php/zend project right now. I installed it locally, everything is fine except the part where the app sends a confirmation mail after the user has completed a form.

the error i have is basically "Connection could not be established"

this is the code :

public function sendMail($user, $gain=null)
{
    global $config;

```
$this->_view->url   = $config->app->url;

$tr = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp($config->app->mail->server);
Zend_Mail::setDefaultTransport($tr);

$mail = new MGMail($config->app->mail->key, true);
$mail->setFrom($config->app->mail->from, $config->app->mail->fromName);

if ($gain == null)
{
    $object = $config->app->mail->object->inscription;
    $render = $this->_view->render('inscription.phtml');
}
else
{
    switch ($gain)
    {
        case 'peignoir':
            $gain_name = 'un '.$gain;
        case 'casquette':
            $gain_name = 'une '.$gain;
    }

    $object = sprintf($config->app->mail->object->gain, $gain_name);
    $render = $this->_view->render($gain.'.phtml');
}

$mail->setSubject($object);
$mail->addTo($user->email, $user->first_name.' '.$user->last_name);
$mail->setBodyText($render);

$mail->send();

$this->saveSendEmail($object, $render, $user);
```

}

```
$config->app->mail->server
```

contains simply "localhost"in my application.ini

What do i need to do to fix this problem ?
Is there any php modules to activate?
 sorry if it's obvious for you, i have not been working on this for a long time...

Comment: is the local machine running the SMTP server and the service is running?  Can you telnet to localhost on the SMTP port?

Comment: i just did it : " impossible to establish a connection "
How can i do to activate it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure you are running the SMTP service locally on the machine you are working on.  You can check this by using telnet to localhost on port 25:

> telnet localhost 25

If it times out, then it is likely you do not have an SMTP server installed or running:

> C:\Users\username>telnet localhost 25
>   Connecting To localhost...Could not open connection to the host, on port 25: Connect failed

That is your problem.

To resolve it, you need to install and configure a mailserver.  I have used hmailserver (www.hmailserver.com) in the past and it worked fine.

Comment: i just did it : " impossible to establish a connection "
How can i do to activate it ?

Comment: Install and configure a mailserver such as hmailserver (http://www.hmailserver.com/)

Comment: configure hmailserver to not require smtp authentication.